# How to create a Neo4J data model from the relationla data format?

Tags: neo4j, graph-databases, neo4jclient

I've following row column data.

[image: Space Mood detail]

How can I model this into Neo4J?

Comment: Questions that ask "where do I start" are typically too broad and are not a good fit for this site. People have their own method for approaching the problem and because of this there cannot be a _correct_ answer. Give a good read over [**Where to Start**](//meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/6366/where-to-start/6367#6367), then address your post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whilst I agree with @kayess that the question is very broad - from a 'guidelines' point of view - Neo4j does provide some information regarding going from RDBMS to Neo4j - [Neo4j Data Import - Moving from RDBMS to Graph](https://neo4j.com/developer/guide-importing-data-and-etl/)

The basic gist from your columns is two types of `Node` - `Space` and `Mood` with a `Relationship` of your choosing - maybe something like `HAS_MOOD` so you have something like:

`(:Space {Name: 'Living Room'})-[:HAS_MOOD]->(:Mood {Name: 'Cheerful'})`